# Hide Wordpress Site URL from Source Code

Tags: plugins, hooks, site-url

How to hide the leading site url from the source code example

```
http://example.com/wp-content/themes/themename/style.css
```

Becomes

```
/wp-content/themes/themename/style.css
```

Removing the main site URL which `http://example.com/` from the source code

I've seen many sites running wordpress however they don't have the Site URL shown in the source code for CSS and JS files.

I know there are many plugins that can help hiding wordpress source code so no one will know it's wordpress however none of them removes the Site URL from files links.

Comment: Can I ask why you want this?

Comment: I want this for many reasons, 1. to hide it's wordpress even if I'm using the plugins or hooks that help me do that however the structure of the CMS is still the same and still detectable. Second I want less load of the files to look as static HTML rather a CMS built website.

Comment: Hiding the domain isn't going to hide that it's WordPress. `wp-content` is right there.

Comment: True however the first step is hiding the domain and the second step using the plugins to mask urls

Answer (score 0):

You can write your css codes inside php file, So your css file becomes `style.css.php`
Then you can put it by `include_once()` in your theme So your css file will not be displayed in your page source code.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for exactly, this solution won't support other files. I'm still looking to hide the leading Site URL of the link